# How do I create a 'next' button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make a Photo Browser GUI, and I need to be able to browse through the photos, how would I Go about making a 'next' button and a 'previous'. I am a complete beginner so any help is appreciated

Comment: Really, do you not know about lists and indices before Tkinter? Just use a list of images and increase the current index on the button press. You can use the modulus operator too to wrap the images after a cycle.

Answer (score 4):

As simple as it can be:

1 - Create a master window, usually name root:

```
root = Tk()
```

2 - Add a Main Frame for Displaying your Picture (current photo):

```
framePhoto = Frame(root, bg='gray50',relief = RAISED, width=800, height=600, bd=4)
```

3 - Add two buttons, Next & Prev:

```
prevBtn = Button(self.framePhoto, text='Previous', command=lambda s=self: s.getImgOpen('prev'),
                bg='blue', fg='red').place(relx=0.85, rely=0.99, anchor=SE)


nextBtn = Button(self.framePhoto, text='Next', command=lambda s=self: s.getImgOpen('next'),
                bg='green', fg='black').place(relx=0.90, rely=0.99, anchor=SE)
```

4 - You need to add method to handle listing all pictures in your current directory or directory that you input to the application, example:

```
def getImgList(self, path, ext):
        imgList = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
        imgList = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in imgList if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ext]
        self.images.extend(imgList)
```

5 - Another method to open and display the image:

```
def getImgOpen(self,seq):
        print 'Opening %s' % seq
        if seq=='ZERO':
            self.imgIndex = 0
        elif (seq == 'prev'):
            if (self.imgIndex == 0):
                self.imgIndex = len(self.images)-1
            else:
                self.imgIndex -= 1
        elif(seq == 'next'):
            if(self.imgIndex == len(self.images)-1):
                self.imgIndex = 0
            else:
                self.imgIndex += 1

        self.masterImg = Image.open(self.images[self.imgIndex]) 
        self.master.title(self.images[self.imgIndex])
        self.masterImg.thumbnail((400,400))
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.masterImg)
        self.lbl['image'] = self.img
        return
```

This is as simple as I can explain to you and the above mentioned piece of codes are for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code, as explained by Iron Fist answer. I assembled it, so I it might be useful.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

class Display(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.images = [];
    self.imgIndex = 0;
    self.master= Tk()
    self.framePhoto = Frame(self.master, bg='gray50',relief = RAISED, width=800, height=600, bd=4)
    self.framePhoto.pack();
    prevBtn = Button(self.framePhoto, text='Previous', command=lambda s=self: s.getImgOpen('prev')).place(relx=0.85, rely=0.99, anchor=SE)
    nextBtn = Button(self.framePhoto, text='Next', command=lambda s=self: s.getImgOpen('next')).place(relx=0.90, rely=0.99, anchor=SE)
    #prevBtn.pack();
    #nextBtn.pack();
    self.getImgList('test_2/test_2','.bmp')
    mainloop()

def getImgList(self, path, ext):
    imgList = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    imgList = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in imgList if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ext]
    self.images.extend(imgList)
    #print self.images

def getImgOpen(self,seq):
    print 'Opening %s' % seq
    if seq=='ZERO':
        self.imgIndex = 0
    elif (seq == 'prev'):
        if (self.imgIndex == 0):
            self.imgIndex = len(self.images)-1
        else:
            self.imgIndex -= 1
    elif(seq == 'next'):
        if(self.imgIndex == len(self.images)-1):
            self.imgIndex = 0
        else:
            self.imgIndex += 1

    self.masterImg = Image.open(self.images[self.imgIndex]) 
    self.master.title(self.images[self.imgIndex])
    self.masterImg.thumbnail((400,400))
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.masterImg)
    label = Label(image=self.img)
    label.image = self.img # keep a reference!
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=100,y=100)
    #self.lbl['image'] = self.img
    return    
d = Display();
d.getImgOpen('next')
```

Comment: Everywhere else I've seen code like this `def __init__(self):` would be indented underneath `class Display(object):`. Also with your call `d = Display();` a parameter isn't being passed but the class shows it expects a parameter?